# child object in parent class method

Tags: c++, polymorphism

In answering [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22648110/error-saying-class-defined-as-public-is-private/22648201#22648201), I noticed something like the following:

```
class A
{
  public:
  A();
  void foo();
};

class B: public A
{
  public:
  B();
};

void A::foo()
{
  B bar;

  //more code
}
```

Intuitively, I want to say this can't be done, but I don't know for sure. Regardless of whether its a good idea to do or not, does anyone know if it's illegal (and why)?

Edit: I rushed the example, I edited the code so the constructors are public.

Comment: I can't see why it can't be done, it [compiles fine](http://ideone.com/IaOJlY).

Comment: Sorry about that, link fixed

Comment: You can't say "irregardless" and pretend you're serious.

Comment: @Kerrek SB I am serious, I just didn't want people to write off the question saying "Don't do that, that's a bad idea". I didn't think the compiler would allow it and I don't understand why it does.

Answer (score 0):

What makes you think it can't be done? The example you gave is invalid, because the constructors are private. But after making `A` and `B` structs, it works perfectly fine (example [here](http://ideone.com/XIDVwd)). There is no rule saying that a base class function cannot have a derived class object.

Answer (score 0):

You have some intuitive feeling about why it seems like it can't be done, which I think is a good sign. When a base classes uses a derived class, the two classes are inter-dependent. It's a pattern that is often encountered but worth trying to avoid. The compiler certainly won't complain about inter-dependent classes.